# Use Double Pointers to access values instead of doubles

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, copy, double-pointer

My question might be a bit confusing because I really did not know how to word it. Essentially, I have three classes in total and two of them are holding double pointers of a type defined in the third class.

```
class Wheel
{
    unsigned m_orderID{};
    std::string m_name{};
};
```

The other two classes - `Car` & `Truck` - have identical private members:

```
class Car{
    const Wheel** m_ptrToArray{};
    size_t m_count{};
};
```

My problem is that, in `main()`, I am making changes to the `Wheel` class values, where the `Truck` needs to have values that change, but the `Car` class needs to remain unchanged. Because the `Car` and `Truck` are both using double pointers, any update to the `Wheel` values changes the output for both  because they are accessing the information via address, if I'm understanding correctly.

I believe my problem lies in the constructor used to create a `Car` object:

```
Car::Car(const Wheel* wheels[], size_t count)
```

I am trying to make a copy of the `Wheel` array that's passed in, so that I can assign the copy to the `Wheel** m_ptrToArray` member. That way, if I update the original array in `main()`, only `Truck` will change and `Car` will remain untouched. But I can't figure out how to do it.

If I use the following code in my constructor:

```
m_ptrToArray = new const Wheel*[m_count];
for (auto i = 0u; i < m_count; i++)
{
    m_ptrToArray[i] = wheels[i];
}
```

It doesn't do what I want, because I'm just assigning the address of the `wheels` array.

If I do:

```
Wheel* temp = new Wheel[m_count];
for (auto i = 0u; i < m_count; i++)
{
    temp[i] = *wheels[i];
}
m_ptrToArray = new const Wheel*[m_count];
for (auto i = 0u; i < m_count; i++)
{
    m_ptrToArray[i] = &temp[i];
}
```

It works correctly, changing `Truck` but not `Car`. However, I run into memory loss because I'm using the `new` keyword without `delete` - because I have no idea how to pass it other than `&temp[i]` which means if I `delete` it, it won't be able to reach the value any more.

I am at a loss. Hopefully, this explanation makes sense to somebody who knows what they are doing. Let me know if you need any more information at all!

Comment: Forget pointers.  Use `std::vector`.  You'll thank me later.  You don't need to use `new` or `delete` when using `std::vector`.   The `std::vector` manages memory so you don't need to.

Comment: Reminder:  Cars and Trucks don't have pointers to wheels (except maybe the spare).  Cars and Trucks **contain** one or more wheels.

Comment: If you can't use `std::vector` because of assignment restrictions, consider writing your own simple version. Often when the instructor says, "No `vector`!" what they really mean is "I'm giving the best grades to the students who write their own `vector`."

Comment: As Thomas says: forget pointers. As much as you can. Really, wipe them from memory. That removes 99% of your problems. But if you must then use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Ah, the [wisdom of the Sith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmVyUdHtxbU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  `Truck` can just save the `Wheel*` pointers it is given, while `Car` can make its own copy of the `Wheel` objects.  Simply destroy those copies in `Car`'s destructor.  That seems to be the piece you are missing.  Simply store the extra objects as an additional member of the `Car` class, instead of using a local variable in the constructor.

Try something like the following (FYI, I'm ignoring the need for copy/move constructors and assignment operators, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). I'll leave that as an exercise for you to implement).

For `Car`:

```
class Car{
    const Wheel** m_ptrToArray{};
    size_t m_count{};
    Wheel* m_wheels{};

public:
    Car(const Wheel* wheels[], size_t count);
    ~Car();
};

...

Car::Car(const Wheel* wheels[], size_t count)
{
    m_count = count;
    m_wheels = new Wheel[count];
    m_ptrToArray = new const Wheel*[count];
    for (auto i = 0u; i < count; ++i)
    {
        m_wheels[i] = *(wheels[i]);
        m_ptrToArray[i] = &m_wheels[i];
    }
}

Car::~Car()
{
    delete[] m_ptrToArray;
    delete[] m_wheels;
}
```

Or simpler:

```
class Car{
    const Wheel** m_ptrToArray{};
    size_t m_count{};

public:
    Car(const Wheel* wheels[], size_t count);
    ~Car();
};

...

Car::Car(const Wheel* wheels[], size_t count)
{
    m_count = count;
    m_ptrToArray = new const Wheel*[count];
    for (auto i = 0u; i < count; ++i)
    {
        m_ptrToArray[i] = new Wheel(*(wheels[i]));
    }
}

Car::~Car()
{
    for (auto i = 0u; i < m_count; ++i)
    {
        delete m_ptrToArray[i];
    }
    delete[] m_ptrToArray;
}
```

And for `Truck`:

```
class Truck{
    const Wheel** m_ptrToArray{};
    size_t m_count{};

public:
    Truck(const Wheel* wheels[], size_t count);
    ~Truck();
};

...

Truck::Truck(const Wheel* wheels[], size_t count)
{
    m_count = count;
    m_ptrToArray = new const Wheel*[count];
    for (auto i = 0u; i < count; ++i)
    {
        m_ptrToArray[i] = wheels[i];
    }
}

Truck::~Truck()
{
    delete[] m_ptrToArray;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to figure out, I can't believe I didn't think to just add a private member that wasn't a double pointer and manage the memory that way.

The only issue I'm having now is that my move constructor isn't able to properly read the values of the double pointer? When I try to move one car into another, the debugger is showing that its not actually passing any information (all unknown addresses i think)

Thank you either way though, at least I can try to figure out a new problem instead of being stuck on the old one!

Comment: Can't edit anymore, but I figured the entire program out. Thanks a lot for sending me in the right direction :)